# navigation from one screen to other screen in android

Tags: android

```
public class Check extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    //private check2 check2;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button usemirror = (Button)findViewById(R.id.widget28);
        usemirror.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    public void onClick(View view){


        Intent mi = new Intent(this , check2.class);
        startActivity(mi);
}
}

package com.exaple;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class check2 extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       // super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Welcome to second page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();  

    }

}
```

ANDROID manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".check2" >
```

I am doing this but doesn't show me the message written in my other activities

Comment: i have declared it in the android menifest xml file but it doesnt work on clicking the button it says"force close"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Uttam Didn't you got `super not called exception`?

I suppose you must call `super.onCreate()` in your check2.Not calling this in your check2 is causing **Force Close**

```
public class check2 extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   //first call super.onCreate()
       Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Welcome to second page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();  

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you still need to add:

```
@Override     
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
}
```

to both first and second activities.

Comment: But after adding this, what are the things to write?

Answer (score 0):

Please change your first activity code as below

```
public class Check extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    //private check2 check2;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Button usemirror = (Button)findViewById(R.id.widget28);
        usemirror.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    public void onClick(View view){


        Intent mi = new Intent(Check.this , check2.class);
        startActivity(mi);
}
}
```

& second activity code as below

```
public class check2 extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   //first call super.onCreate()
       Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Welcome to second page", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();  

    }
```

Comment: have changed as u told but same problem occured

Comment: Can please post the Logcat trace which clears about why it says force close.